# Display a subvalue in a pie chart

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I'm working on waste management data in a coastal town. I'd like to create a pie chart of this, and to display a subvalue inside the area of a higher value. The picture below will maybe help:

[image: Waste Management Data]

I'd like to show the contribution of coastal litter inside the bigger litter compartment, to put the orange compartment inside the blue one. I've been looking around but couldn't find the answer to my question, and please excuse me if this question has been posted before.

Comment: Have you looked at the different pie chart options? Maybe a donut chart will do what you want. Can you [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1505273/edit) to include an example of the desired result?

Comment: Did you mean you want the merge data in the Pie Chart with the same color based on the left data?

Comment: @Lee, In a way yes. I'd like to have a kind of dotted line inside the blue compartment, with a value of 220. My coastal waste is just a sub value of the total 561 tons. So what would be great is to have the total waste in blue, and a line at 220 so that we can see that inside the general waste, 220 tons are linked to coastal areas...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do this.

I first made a pie chart with all of the data but ignoring the coastal waste. I added data labels (with category and value) to each point and deleted the legend, and I also did not explode the chart.

[image: Pie Chart Without Subvalue]

Then I made a second data range, with the waste split into coastal and non coastal. I copied this data, selected the chart, and used Paste Special to add the data as a new series with categories in the first column.

I right-clicked on a chart series, chose Change Series Chart Type, selected the second series in the dialog, changed it to a donut chart type, and check the Secondary Axis box.

I formatted all of the donut segments to have no fill. I gave coastal waste a bold black border, and I gave the rest no border. And I gave coastal waste a data label.

[image: Pie Chart with Subvalue as Donut Segment]

When I tried this the first time, I wanted a full pie segment for coastal waste, but I couldn't make it work. So I used the donut approach above. Then I tried again using a pie, and it worked. Go figure. It's important that the added series is on the secondary axis (even though a pie chart has no axes, it still can have multiple series separated into axis groups). I thought a dashed line worked better here than a solid line, and a white line better than black.

[image: Pie Chart with Subvalue as Secondary Pie Segment]